# How to set dataset to row

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

My table has below records, and what I need is set below results into datatable.

```
date        code      lc_code      qty
7/1/2018    MC20651    1126         322.00
7/1/2018    MC10102    3356         30.00
7/1/2018    MC10201    4422         56.00
7/1/2018    MC10303    5065         55.00
7/1/2018    MC20902    7012         65.00
7/1/2018    MC50201    1258         45.00
7/1/2018    MC10201    1126         86.00
7/1/2018    MC50201    7012         14.25
7/1/2018    MC20651    1258         322.00
7/1/2018    MC20651    3356         78.00
```

Here  below is what I need to set to datatable. Can you provide the best query to do that?

---

```
|  Code     |   1126 |   3356 |   4422 |   5065  |   7012 |   1258 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MC20651  |  322.00|   78.00|   0.00 |   0.00  |   0.00 | 322.00 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MC10102  |   0.00 |  30.00 |   0.00 |   0.00  |   0.00 |   0.00 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MC10201  |   86.00|   0.00 |  56.00 |   0.00  |   0.00 | 134.25 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MC10303  |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 |  55.00  |   0.00 |   0.00 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MC20902  |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 | 960.00  |  65.00 |   0.00 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|  MC50201  |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00  |  14.25 |   45.00|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos tried but not get exactly answer,once tried using union but its not work.if there any query to slove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using `max(case when ... end)` functions and grouping by `code`, it is a common way to pivot data in T-SQL:

Sample data:

```
create table tbl(date date, code  char(10), lc_code int, qty float);
insert into tbl (code,lc_code,qty) values
('MC20651', 1126, 322.00),
('MC10102', 3356, 30.00),
('MC10201', 4422, 56.00),
('MC10303', 5065, 55.00),
('MC20902', 7012, 65.00),
('MC50201', 1258, 45.00),
('MC10201', 1126, 86.00),
('MC50201', 7012, 14.25),
('MC20651', 1258 , 322.00),
('MC20651', 3356, 78.00);
```

T-SQL:

```
select  `code`
        `1126`,
        `3356`,
        `4422`, 
        `5065`,
        `7012`,
        `1258`,
        `1126` + `3356` + `4422` + `5065` + `7012` + `1258` `sum`
from (
    select `code`,
           max(case lc_code when 1126 then qty else 0 end) `1126`,
           max(case lc_code when 3356 then qty else 0 end) `3356`,
           max(case lc_code when 4422 then qty else 0 end) `4422`,
           max(case lc_code when 5065 then qty else 0 end) `5065`,
           max(case lc_code when 7012 then qty else 0 end) `7012`,
           max(case lc_code when 1258 then qty else 0 end) `1258`
    from tbl
    group by `code`
) `a`;
```

Comment: Thanks bro,Case save me :)

Comment: @ Michał Turczyn is there any chance to get sum of row end of the coulmn.

Comment: HI @Michał Turczyn Thanks for you quick replying but i need that sum end of the row not in column :(

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine (Y),and update your answer `code`,   ;)